# General approach to Delta Epsilon Continuity Proofs

Tags: optimization, continuity, proof-writing

I am currently studying for an exam in Mathematical research tools. One concept that has come up again and again throughout the course is continuity and although the definition of Cauchy Continuity or Delta Epsilon continuity was discussed, we were never shown how to actually prove that a function is continuous. Therefore I am very interested if there is a. general approach that one can take if one wants to prove continuity of simple one variable functions like X^2 or the square root of x etc. Any sort of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just googled, delta-epsilon proofs to find this one here: http://www.milefoot.com/math/calculus/limits/DeltaEpsilonProofs03.htm. They layout how to construct one, which may be good practice.

Comment: Hey Jack, thank you very much this is super helpful!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prove that the function $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$ you need to show that for a given $\epsilon >0$ you can  find a $\delta>0$ such that  if $$|x-a|<\delta$$ then $$|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon $$

For example if $f(x)=x^2$ and $a=5$ you have to show that $$|x-5|<\delta \implies |x^2-25|<\epsilon $$

The trick is to factor $$|x^2-25| = |(x-5)||(x+5)| <|x+5|\delta $$
Now if  $\delta <1$ then we have $ |x+5|<6$ so $$|x^2-25| = |(x-5)||(x+5)| <|x+5|\delta <6\delta <\epsilon $$ provided that $$\delta =\min \{\epsilon /6, 1\}$$

Yes, it is complicated at first but gets better with practice.

Comment: Thank you very much ! This helps a lot already, I was wondering can I also use this approach if I have to prove that a function is continuous at every point or for any a?

Comment: @MarcelHinss Yes all you have to do change $a$ to say $x_0$

Answer (score 0):

To prove $f(x) $ is continuous at $x = c$  we must prove the limit of $\lim_{x\to c}f(x) = c$.

So for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta_\epsilon > 0$ so that whenever $|x-c|< \delta_\epsilon$ it will follow that $|f(x)-f(c)|< \delta$.

There are two strategies

1)  Start with $|x-c| < \delta$

$-\delta < x-c < \delta$

$c-\delta < x <c+\delta$

do series of manipulations on $x$ to get

$SOMETHINGTODOWITHDELTA < f(x) - f(c) <SOMETHINGELSETODOWITHDELTA$

And find a way to have a $\epsilon_{\delta}$ based on $\delta$ so that

$-\epsilon_{\delta} \le SOMETHINGTODOWITHDELTA < f(x) - f(c) <SOMETHINGELSETODOWITHDELTA +\epsilon_\delta$

And then express $\delta$ in terms $\epsilon$

Example:  Prove $f(x) = \sqrt{4x +1}$ is continuous at $x = 12$.

That's a matter of proving $\lim_{x\to 12} f(x)=\sqrt{4x +1} = f(12)=7$.

So if $|x -12| <\delta$ then

$-\delta < x-12 < \delta$

$49 -4\delta < 4x +1 < 49 +4\delta$

Now we can assume $\delta < \frac{49}4$.  If $|x-c| < \delta \implies something$ then $|x-c|< smaller\delta < \delta \implies something$ so we are allow to assume $\delta$ is as small as we need it to be.

$\sqrt{49-4\delta} < \sqrt{4x+1} < \sqrt{49+4\delta}$.

Now if we express $7-\epsilon \le \sqrt{49-4\delta}$ and $\sqrt{49+4\delta} \le 7+\epsilon$ we will be done.

We can assume $\epsilon$ is as small as we like.  We need to prove that there is a $\delta$ that shows $|f(x)-f(c)|< \epsilon$ and if instead we find a $\delta$ shows $|f(x)-f(c)|< smaller\epsilon < \epsilon$ that will be good enough.  So we can assume $\epsilon < 7$

So we need

$0 < 7-\epsilon \le \sqrt{49-4\delta}< \sqrt{49+4\delta} \le 7+4\epsilon$

Or

$49- 14\epsilon + \epsilon^2 \le {49-4\delta}< 49+4\delta \le 49 -14\epsilon + \epsilon^2$

$-14\epsilon + \epsilon^2 \le -4\delta \le 14\epsilon +\epsilon^2$.

If we pick $\epsilon < 1$ then $\epsilon^2 < \epsilon$ so

$-14\epsilon + \epsilon^2 < -13\epsilon \le 14\epsilon + \epsilon^2 < 15\epsilon$.

If we can force $|4\delta| < 13\epsilon$ we are done i.e. if

$\delta < \frac {13}4\epsilon$ and $\epsilon <1$ then

$|x-7|<\delta \implies$

$\sqrt{49-4\delta} < \sqrt{4x + 1} < \sqrt{49+\delta}$

$\sqrt{49-13\epsilon} < \sqrt{49-4\delta} < \sqrt{4x + 1} < \sqrt{49+\delta} < \sqrt{49+13\epsilon}$ so

$\sqrt{49-14\epsilon + \epsilon^2}<\sqrt{49-13\epsilon} < \sqrt{4x + 1}  < \sqrt{49+13\epsilon} < \sqrt{49 + 14\epsilon + \epsilon^2}$

so $7-\epsilon < \sqrt{4x+1} < 7 +\epsilon$

$-\epsilon < \sqrt{4x+1} -7 < \epsilon$

$|\sqrt{4x+1}-7|<\epsilon$.

So $\lim_{x\to 12}\sqrt{4x + 1}=7=\sqrt{4*12+1}$ so $\sqrt{4x+1}$ is continuous at $x = 12$.

Method 2:

We start with $|f(x)-f(c)| < \epsilon$

$f(c) -\epsilon < f(x) < f(c) +\epsilon$.

Manipulate *with steps that are reversable* to get

$SOMETHINGTODOWITHEPSILON < x < SOMETHINGELSETDOITHEPSILON$

And try to find some $\delta_\epsilon$ in terms of $\epsilon$ where

$SOMETHINGTODOWITHEPSILON\le c+ \delta_\epsilon < x <c-\delta_\epsilon \le SOMETHINGELSETDOITHEPSILON$

Then you have (assuming ever step is reversable) $|x-c|<\delta_\epsilon \implies |f(x) - f(c) | <\epsilon$.

Example:

Example:  Prove $f(x) = \sqrt{4x +1}$ is continuous at $x = 12$.

That's a matter of proving $\lim_{x\to 12} f(x)=\sqrt{4x +1} = f(12)=7$.

So to conclude $|\sqrt{4x+1} - 7| < \epsilon$ we can show that from

$0<7-\epsilon < \sqrt{4x+1} < 7+\epsilon$.

And that will follow from $\epsilon < 1$ and

$0< 49 -14\epsilon+\epsilon^2 < 4x+1 < 49 + 14 \epsilon +\epsilon^2$

If we assume $\epsilon < 1$ then $\epsilon^2 < \epsilon$ and we will have the above result if we have

$48 -14\epsilon+\epsilon^2<48 - 13\epsilon < 4x < 48 + 13\epsilon < 48-+14\epsilon + \epsilon^2$.

or equivalently $12 -\frac{13}4\epsilon < x < 12 + \frac{13}4 \epsilon$

or equivalently if $|x-12|< \frac{13}4\epsilon$.

So if we are given and $\epsilon$ and we relabel $\epsilon = \min(\epsilon, 1)$ and we set $\delta =\frac{13}4\min(\epsilon, 1)$ then we will get

$|x-12|<\delta \implies$

$|f(x) -7|<\epsilon$.

So $\lim_{x\to 12}\sqrt{4x+1} = 7=\sqrt{4(12)+1}$ so

$\sqrt{4x+1}$ is continuous at $x = 12$.

Comment: Thank you so much Fleablood, This is a great great help, it will take me some time to understand everything but it is super helpful already and thank you for all the effort you put into writing this!!!